# Clone bitbucket repo to local machine failed

Tags: git, ssh, terminal, bitbucket

I'm trying to clone my repository from bitbucket:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:myname/mynamerepo.git
```

and getting error:

```
Cloning into 'folder_name'...
conq: repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with 
the requested repository.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The problem happened after i've installed new clean mac os on my laptop. Generated new ssh key and added it to bitbucket ssh keys but still no luck.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7235/missed-access-to-all-my-repositories-conq) can help you. Double check that the key your client is offering is the one associated with your account by running "ssh -v git@bitbucket.org".

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting the system and generating the new key helped :-/